# Unable to create object class extension COM component?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, feature-class

I'm getting the error:

> Unable to create object class extension COM component

in ArcMap 10.2 when trying to open feature classes from old geodatabases.

I'm also getting "error repairing the layer" when trying to open other feature classes from the same old personal geodatabases.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you know if these featureclasses relied on custom class extensions?

Comment: yes, it did. Is there an effective way to remove class extensions? Because I don't want to install a driver to read them. thanks

Comment: Programmatically this can be done via [IFeatureWorkspaceSchemaEdit.AlterClassExtensionCLSID](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000325000000).  Not sure of a way to do it through the UI.  If it's a personal mdb, you might try looking for a row in the ObjectClasses table for your featureclass, and clear out the EXTCLSID value for that row.  Back up your mdb first.

Comment: Of course the best thing to do would be to find the dll and register it in the "GeoObject Class Extensions" category using categories.exe.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Okay Great! I clear out the EXTCLSID values but now i am getting an error "Failed to paste ___ the domain was not found. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps this would indicate that fields in your featureclass reference domains that are not found in the workspace. Do you have any domains in the workspace?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I have domains in my database

Comment: In arccatalog, can you see if any of the fields in your featureclass reference domains not found in the workspace?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall They don't reference domains not found in the workspace. and the featureclass doesn't reference the domain that can't be found so i'm not sure why it still would let me paste. And thanks again for all your help